# Mantener valores aun que se apague el dispositivo Android

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo una pequeña apk para android y me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de guardar variables de la apk aunque el dispositivo se apague.
Por ejemplo en mi caso el usuario añade valores a una lista para después mostrarla en un dialog. Hay algún método para que esa lista quede modificada y no se inicie siempre con los valores por defecto?

Answer (score 2):

Más bien lo que estás intentando hacer es guardar un estado de la app, te recomiendo le eches un vistazo a SQLite, es para guardar datos en una base de datos local, revisa este link https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite?hl=es-419